# Datagrid save value in Database when cell change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Hi I create this test code:

```
<Button x:Name="b_Delete" Content="Delete" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Button x:Name="b_Save" Content="Save" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Books, Mode=TwoWay,
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Author" Header="Author"
                            Width="*" Binding="{Binding author, Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Title" Header="Title"
                            Width="*" Binding="{Binding title}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Price" Header="Price"
                            Width="*" Binding="{Binding price}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Delete_Row" Header="Delete" Width="0.2*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="X"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have create two button and a `DataGrid`. To `DataGrid` is fill with values read into database, now if the user change the text into the cell, the new value is saved into the database (the button X delete into the row is not implemented for now).

My idea is make one `ObservableCollection where I add the information of row changed (another` ObservableCollect`for row deleted) and When the button Save is clicked, I save the value into Database taking the value into`ObservableCollect`. What do you think?

How can I intercept the change of value in the cell of the `DataGrid`?

```
private ObservableCollection<Book> books = null;
public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
{
    get { return books; }
    set
    {
        books = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This point is not call if I change the cell value?

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to handle this, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend "intercepting" the changes to track them (especially if you're using a "Save" button). Instead, when you load the `Books` list from the database, I would make two copies: `Books` and `BooksOriginal` (or some similar name). `Books` would be an `ObservableCollection<T>`, but `BooksOriginal` can just be a normal `List<T>` since it won't be used in binding.

Bind the `DataGrid` to `Books` and let the user add, delete or update any records they want. Then, when they click "Save", you compare `Books` to `BooksOriginal` to decide what to do with each item:

- If the item from `Books` isn't in `BooksOriginal`, it's new and needs to be inserted into the database.
- If the item from `Books` is in `BooksOriginal`, compare the two versions to see if they're different. If so, changes were made and you need to update the record in the database.
- Finally, check for items in `BooksOriginal` that aren't in `Books`, those will be records that have been deleted from the `DataGrid`.

This way databinding can just do its job, you only have to worry about two variables (`Books` and `BooksOriginal`), and all the logic/code gets kept in one method: `Save`.

A couple notes:
This assumes each record has a unique identifier.

Make sure, if you use the two collections idea as above, that you make *two separate objects* for each "book". Don't make one book object and add it to both collections or you won't be able to compare for changes.

You also have the option of only making one list (`Books`) when the program loads, and then loading the second list (`BooksOriginal`) when they click save. This has the advantage of making sure the you have the most current data from the database when checking for changes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion I will follow.